# Sublime Text 2 - Package Control Error

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I cannot access the Package Control repo any more.

When I try to install a package, I get following error message in a popup window

```
Package Control. There are no packages available for installation.
```

and in the Sublime console

```
Package Control: Error downloading channel. URL error 65 downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json.
error: Package Control

There are no packages available for installation
```

Right now (March 7th 2015, 23:40 CET) I cannot access the Sublime Package Control site (https://packagecontrol.io/) in the browser either. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about whether or not a third-party service is down.  You should ask at the service's support instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing is happening to me as well. I've tested on multiple computer at multiple locations and each one is throwing the same error.

It has nothing to do with your setup so just wait it out. I don't expect this to last very long.

Comment: Indeed, after some time the service recovered... Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a proxy and Package Control doesn't know it. Press CMD + SHIFT + P, then enter `Preferences: Package Control Settings - User` and add http_proxy or/and https_proxy parameters:

```
"http_proxy": "webproxy_address.com:3100",
"https_proxy": "webproxy_address.com:3100",
```

And then reload Sublime.